# PHP - Not able to get Text field value

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP, I have mentioned below my HTML and PHP codes. I am not able to get the textbox value to PHP. I have mentioned below both HTML and PHP codes.

HTML Code:

```
Section <input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_sec" id="f_b1_s1_sec">
Content <input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_con" id="f_b1_s1_con"><br><br> 
Para <input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_para" id="f_b1_s1_para">
```

PHP Code:

```
$tx0 = $_POST["f_b1_s1_sec"];
$tx1 = $_POST["f_b1_s1_con"];
$tx2 = $_POST["f_b1_s1_para"];
```

Please Clarify.

Thank you!

Comment: u need a <form action="post">

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty you actually need it to say `<form method="POST">` instead of `<form action="post">`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty - you need `<form method="post" action="mypage.php">`. Action is where the form is sent, method is **how** the form is sent.

Comment: you may want to post your full code. For all we know you're not even posting to the right file

Comment: @ Arian; If I use "array_key_exists("f_b1_s1_sec", $_POST);" it is give 1 as output, but when I try to access the field using "$_POST["f_b1_s1_sec"];", it does not give any output.

Comment: @RamasamyRaja Use if(isset($_POST['f_B!_s1_sec']) && $_POST['f_B!_s1_sec']) != '' ) instead. It checks to see if $_POST['f_B!_s1_sec'] exists then makes sure it isn't an empty string, which would happen if the page is sent without the form being filled in either by a user or a web crawler bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST["go"] ) {
  $tx0 = $_POST["f_b1_s1_sec"];
  $tx1 = $_POST["f_b1_s1_con"];
  $tx2 = $_POST["f_b1_s1_para"];
}
?>

<form action="insertyourphp.php" method="post">
Section <input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_sec" id="f_b1_s1_sec">
Content <input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_con" id="f_b1_s1_con"><br><br> 
Para <input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_para" id="f_b1_s1_para">
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: **NOTE:** If the php and the html are in the same file... you can omit `action="insertyourphp.php"`